# Run cronjob for missing time periods

Tags: cron, cron-task

I Have crontab set up (on my local MacOSX system) to run a job on a per hourly basis. It runs fine. I am not sure if it is possible, but is there a way that I can run the job for 'missing' hours (in case my computer sleeps or I shut it down)?

For example if cronjob ran fine for hours (1-13) before I shut down the system. I start up the system again after, lets say 2 hours. Is there a way to tell cron to run the job for missing hours (14,15) too before executing hour 16?

The cronjob currently running fills up some data in my local MySQL DB with hour information in one of the columns. Any tips, tricks or libraries will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at *anacron* for Mac that can catch up jobs missed while your Mac was sleeping the next time it wakes up. See [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031111110802488).